# Turn black borders around a custom region of interest to transparent

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I process images to have a custom region of interest, after getting the desired region the rest of the image is in black borders. What I want is to turn the black borders to transparent.

I use this code to get my ROI:

```
# preprocess
mask = np.zeros(frame.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
roi_corners = np.array([[(850,0), (220,1500), (2250,1500),(1450,0)]], dtype=np.int32)
channel_count = frame.shape[2]
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)
frame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, mask)
```

This is an example of my images after preprocessing: 
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: An image would always be in the shape of a rectangle. So you won't be able to crop in any irregular format. However you may choose to replace the black with 0 alpha so that it becomes transparent.

Comment: does changing pixels to transparent the same as changing them to white?

Comment: No, transparent is not white. If there's something blue behind a transparent image, you'll see the blue through it, whereas you will not with white. Transparency is more useful than white because it is a whole, separate channel which says for each pixel whether it is visible or not. If you use white, you cannot differentiate between borders and white pixels naturally occurring elsewhere in your image.